# How to select unique value randomly from a table in heavy load server

Tags: php, mysql

I have a single-column MySQL database table `ids` (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT) where I store pre-generated unique ids in an ascending order. In order to get a random id from that table I use this query:

```
SELECT id FROM ids ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

And now I am wondering how to ensure that the id I got is never used again. I see two options. One is to delete the id from the table and the other is add a column tracking the use of that id:

```
DELETE FROM ids WHERE id=?; //where id is the one I got from the previous query
```

or

```
SELECT id FROM ids WHERE used=0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1; 
UPDATE ids SET used=1 WHERE id=?; //where used is new column with 0 as default value
```

There is only a slight problem with both of these. If the server load is heavy then two queries for a random id might return the same id before it gets removed from the list (or disabled with used column).

Would transaction help?

Comment: MySQL doesn't seem like the right tool for this task. What's preventing you from generating an ID when you need it instead of pregenerating and producing this problem? If you pregenerate, what about storing them in Redis or something else with atomic set add/remove operations?

Comment: @Kristján I need random unique ID without further meaning. That means I cannot generate it when I need it because it would rely on auto-increment or would require progressively more demanding loops. Unfortunately I cannot use other database than MySQL so Redis is not an option. But you set me on the right track along with the other commenters about MySQL FOR UPDATE clause. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping your select and your update in a transaction will work. If you want to avoid a transaction as well as the race condition between selecting your item and marking it unusable, you can run the `UPDATE` first. You'll need a way for each of your processes to identify itself as the owner of the row between claiming it and deletion. For example, assume your `ids` schema is

- `id` (integer)
- `owner` (string)

Have each process pick a UUID (or something else suitably unique) and run the following:

1. `UPDATE ids SET owner = $process_id WHERE owner IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`
2. `SELECT id FROM ids WHERE owner = $process_id`
3. `DELETE FROM ids WHERE id = $selected_id` (or otherwise mark it used)

Step 1 atomically claims the row for the process so that no other process can claim it. Step 2 pulls out the claimed ID. Step 3 removes the ID from the available set for good. If Step 3 doesn't delete the row, just marks it used, make sure you clear `owner` as well so your process won't select it again later.

Comment: Thank you I think that this would work although I think the MySQL locking read feature is a better choice: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html. However when using your idea the the session ID could be used instead of generating new process uuid.

Comment: After some testing I have concluded that the idea of owning the row before selecting it is actually better than FOR UPDATE clause. It is because FOR UPDATE locks all rows the select touches which is all rows in a table due to using the rand() function. It therefore effectively locks the whole table. This approach while having some overhead with uuid (can be replaced with session id) and extra query (for owning the stuff) does not suffer from this problem allowing concurrent pulls from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra column to your `ids` table. Let us say `selected`. You will update this column when it is generated in your randomized query.

`1` for selected and `0` for not yet.

For example

```
SELECT id FROM ids ORDER BY RAND() WHERE selected = 0 LIMIT 1;

$id = $row['id']; /* STORE THE SELECTED ID TO A VARIABLE */
```

Then update the table with

```
UPDATE ids SET selected = 1 WHERE id = $id
```

So that your next run of your randomized query will only get the row of selected `0` value, and not the one with `1` value.

Comment: I don't understand why this prevents accidentally selecting the same Id with different processes at exactly the same time? In Oracle you could use `select for update`to block the row for other processes until you commit your `selected`-Flag. Don't know if there is a simmilar concept in mysql.

Comment: @pala_ Thanks! This seems like the right answer. FOR UPDATE clause (Locking reads" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) inside transaction would prevent the issue even in MySQL. Would you please post it as an answer so I could mark it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could try updating the id 1st before selecting it. try this one.

```
        -- get firstID
        SELECT @MinID:=id FROM ids ORDER by id ASC LIMIT 1; 
        -- get last id
        SELECT @MaxID:=id FROM ids ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1; 
        -- get random id
        SELECT @rndomID :=ROUND((RAND() * (@MaxID-@MinID))+@MinID);
        -- update first
        UPDATE ids SET used=1 WHERE id=@rndomID;
        -- select the id
        SELECT id FROM ids WHERE used=0 WHERE id=@rndomID;
```